# Vercel deploy static files issue Node js

Tags: node.js, vercel

Am basically trying to deploy my node js web application to vercel

am using the fs file system to read the files as shown below in the code block
index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const ejs = require('ejs');
const port = 5000;
const fs = require('fs')
// setting up static files 
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.set('view engine' , 'ejs')


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('./views/index/index.ejs' ,(err,data)=> {
    if(err){
      throw err
    }
    res.write(data)
  })
 
});

// Listen on port 5000
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is booming on port 5000
Visit http://localhost:5000`);
});
```

when i deploy it to vercel with all the configurations

i keep hitting this err-

in the vercel functions log

```
[HEAD] /
08:45:29:46
2021-12-01T03:15:29.528Z    e9aaeb66-7ea2-4af9-88c3-e9790dae7d3d    ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './views/index/index.ejs'","code":"ENOENT","errno":-2,"syscall":"open","path":"./views/index/index.ejs","stack":["Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './views/index/index.ejs'"]}
Unknown application error occurred
```

Comment: Can we see the full directory structure of your project ?

Answer (score 0):

have you added vercel.json in the root directory of your project?

https://kanakkholwal.medium.com/how-to-deploy-your-node-js-backend-on-vercel-a-step-by-step-guide-21796db74601

go through this link One more thing: make sure u have written this

```
 "src": "./index.js", intead of this ` "src": "index.js",`
```